# Return data from nested array

Tags: php, arrays, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get some data from Wikipedia API. I found this project https://github.com/donwilson/PHP-Wikipedia-Syntax-Parser but I cannot figure out how to output the infobox entries in a loop, because the `array` is in an `array` which is in an `array`.

The array code

```
    [infoboxes] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] =>  musical artist 
                [type_key] => musical_artist
                [contents] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => name
                                [value] => George Harrison <br /><small>[[Order of the British Empire|MBE]]</small>
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => image
                                [value] => George Harrison 1974 edited.jpg
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => alt
                                [value] => Black-and-white shot of a moustachioed man in his early thirties with long, dark hair.
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => caption
                                [value] => George Harrison at the White House in 1974.
                            )


                    )

            )

    )
```

This is what I tried (returns the value but not the key)

```
$values=$parsed_wiki_syntax["infoboxes"][0]["contents"];
$keys = array_keys($values);

for($i=0; $i<count($values); $i++){
    foreach ($values[$keys[$i]] as $key=>$value)
        echo "<b>".$key."</b>: ".$value."<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's just see what happens when we simplify everything a little bit:

```
$firstBox = reset($parsed_wiki_syntax['infoboxes']);
if($firstBox) {
    foreach($firstBox['contents'] as $content) {
        $key = $content['key'];
        $value = $content['value'];
        echo "<b>" . $key . "</b>: " . $value . "<br><br>";
    }
}
```

---

The use of `array_keys()` and the `for`/`foreach` loops get a little confusing quickly, so I'm not sure exactly what your error is without looking more.  The big trick with my code above is the use of [`reset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) which resets an array and returns (the first element).  This lets us grab the first `infobox` and check if it exists in the next line (before attempting to get the `contents` of a non-existent key).  Next, we just loop through all `contents` of this first `infobox` and access the `key` and `value` keys directly.

Comment: Still not working. Maybe I need an index. I am confused. Did you try it...did it work?

Comment: It loops and I can see the colon but it doesn't return the values.

Comment: Can you try turning on [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)?

Answer (score 0):

You if want to access both keys and values, a simple good ol' foreach will do. Consider this example:

```
$values = array('infoboxes' => array(array('type' => 'musical artist','type_key' => 'musical_artist','contents' => array(array('key' => 'name', 'value' => 'George Harrison <br /><small>[[Order of the British Empire|MBE]]</small>'),array('key' => 'image', 'value' => 'George Harrison 1974 edited.jpg'),array('key' => 'alt', 'value' => 'Black-and-white shot of a moustachioed man in his early thirties with long, dark hair.'),array('key' => 'caption', 'value' => 'George Harrison at the White House in 1974.'),),),),);
$contents = $values['infoboxes'][0]['contents'];
foreach($contents as $key => $value) {
    echo "[key => " . $value['key'] . "][value = " . htmlentities($value['value']) . "]<br/>";
    // just used htmlentities just as to not mess up the echo since there are html tags inside the value
}
```

Sample Output:

```
[key => name][value = George Harrison <br /><small>[[Order of the British Empire|MBE]]</small>]
[key => image][value = George Harrison 1974 edited.jpg]
[key => alt][value = Black-and-white shot of a moustachioed man in his early thirties with long, dark hair.]
[key => caption][value = George Harrison at the White House in 1974.]
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/unJvRV)

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise in scanning the given array without hardcoding  anything.

It doesn't simplify anything, it is not as clear as some of the other answers,  however, it would process any structure like this whatever the keys were.

It uses the 'inherited' iterator, that all arrays have, for the 'types' and foreach for the contents.

```
<?php
$values = array('infoboxes' => array(array('type' => 'musical artist','type_key' => 'musical_artist','contents' => array(array('key' => 'name', 'value' => 'George Harrison <br /><small>[[Order of the British Empire|MBE]]</small>'),array('key' => 'image', 'value' => 'George Harrison 1974 edited.jpg'),array('key' => 'alt', 'value' => 'Black-and-white shot of a moustachioed man in his early thirties with long, dark hair.'),array('key' => 'caption', 'value' => 'George Harrison at the White House in 1974.'),),),),);

$typeList = current(current($values));
echo key($typeList), ' => ', current($typeList), '<br />';
next($typeList);

echo key($typeList), ' => ', current($typeList), '<br />';
next($typeList);

echo key($typeList), '...', '<br />';
foreach(current($typeList) as $content) {
    $key = current($content);
    next($content);
    echo 'content: ', $key, ' => ', current($content), '<br />' ;
}
```